# Problem in Xcode

Tags: opencv, ocr, xcode

Now i currently working on my OCR and Opencv on the  xcode for my **Final year project**  .

Can someone help me with this problem that i encounter :

```
**error: opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory 
error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory 
error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory 
error: opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory 
error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory 
error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory 
error: map: No such file or directory  
error: string: No such file or directory  
error: iostream: No such file or directory  
error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'public'  
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CvMLData'  
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cv'**
```

Thank you ....

Comment: How did you install OpenCV on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that `iostream` and `string` are not found makes me think that you haven't told Xcode that you are compiling C++. You need to give the file the extension `.mm` (for Objective-C++) or `.cpp` (for straight C++).

There's more info about using OpenCV with Xcode on the [OpenCV Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port). Look at Section 2.

**Update**

There's still something weird going on if `iostream` isn't being found. Try this to see if the problem is independent of OpenCV. See if you can get this program to run:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you should post a new question about how to get it to work. Then you'll have the entire OS X community to help you instead of the few of us who look at OpenCV questions.

Comment: But i have change the file to .mm. But i cant understand your sentence "(for Objective-C++) or .cpp (for straight C++)."

Comment: If the file extension is `.cpp` you can write in C++ but not use any Objective C. If the file extension is `.mm` you can mix C++ and Objective-C, which is referred to as Objective-C++.